# No more reviews for today, for close vote Why?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

Today I am reviewing close votes. After doing some vote cast, System show me a message: **You have no more close votes today; come back in 6 hours.**

[image]

As per my knowledge for each day there are 40 reviews in close vote section, but it gives me this message after 38 reviews only.

You can see the status here:

[image]

Questions:

1. Is this a bug in system or there are any other reason?
2. Is there I have made any mistake in review?
3. Is it possible to have such condition in other review, I have many times that for other reviews section somebody has done 21 review for a day. but here is opposite for me !!! Why?

Comment: You sure are awfully quick at reviewing duplicates... 5 per minute?

Comment: @BoltClock I am there is such reason.

Comment: While you're here, we have some concerns about several of your recent reviews: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7473915 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7434206 . I think you need to slow down and take a little more time reading the things you are reviewing.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you have used all your close votes, between the close votes queue and 'organically' closing questions *outside* of the queue.

For example, if I went and reviewed 20 questions in the close vote review queue, and voted to close all of them, I will now have 30 close votes left for the day. If I then voted to close 30 questions outside of the queue, I.e. by finding them on the homepage, I would now have **0** close votes left.

The close vote queue knows this, and won't let me review any more - because I wouldn't be able to cast a close vote on those questions that I think should be closed, and that's the whole point of the queue. I would have only done 20 close vote reviews that day, but I still wouldn't be able to review any more.

This is what you're running up against, only with slightly different numbers.

Answer (score 8):

1. It's not a bug. You're out of close votes. You get 50 per day, and you used them all. 37 of them you used in review.
2. It's quite possible that you've made *multiple* mistakes; as others have noted, you reviewed those 38 questions *very* quickly. 37 you voted to close, 1 you opted to leave open; we've been working hard to reduce the false-positive rate of questions entering close review, but a 97% close rate is significantly higher than average. You might want to slow down and think a bit harder about the questions you're reviewing before making your decision.
3. Yes, this scenario is possible in several other review queues: if you're out of flags, you can't Triage (because that would prevent you from flagging questions that needed it if you came across one), if you're out of votes you can't review in First Posts or Late Answers (because that would prevent you from voting up/down when the post warrants) and if you're out of reopen votes you can't review in the Reopen queue.

Comment: Thanks man, this is really need full thing to me learn and hope for other also.

Comment: 97% close rate is... really? why don't you ban me, then? [My rate is full 100% close](http://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat?tab=activity&sort=reviews "anyone can see, it's public") (except for known good audits)

Comment: Are you honestly surprised to learn you're an outlier, @gnat? I mean... It's not like this is the *only* area where that observation applies...

Comment: I would be surprised to learn that I'm outlier in preferring to focus strictly on close-worthy questions

Comment: You're in the 1% of close reviewers who've done more than 1000 reviews over the past month, @gnat. And out of that group, only 4 people *skip* tasks more often than you. You've likely found an effective strategy, but it's one that eludes most others.

Comment: ah, outlier "by strategy", I see. That's... rather sad. Not surprising though, since there are no badges to help people learn about [filtering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223887/165773) and [skipping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232052/165773 "fairly sensible request got tons of downvotes solely because of lame comment, that's soooo meta..."). You can't seriously expect reviewers learn about the right approach by searching for obscure meta posts